# cant locate keystore after switching to mac from windows

Tags: android, flutter, keystore

I generated a keystore in my previous laptop which was on windows7. Then I signed my flutter app with that key and uploaded my first version to google playstore.

Recently I switched to mac, so I moved my keystore and changed its directory accordingly. But got the following error

```
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.                
> Keystore file '/Users/sihoonkim/Desktop/dev/mannabox/mannabox_webview_key/key.jks ' not found for signing config 'release'.
```

I tripple checked if the `key.jks` file is in '/Users/sihoonkim/Desktop/dev/mannabox/mannabox_webview_key/key.jks '.

Comment: I can see there is a space at the end of your keystore file location. Remove the space in your config and you should be good to go.

Comment: wow thank you so much!! I had no idea that space would matter! it solved the issue